# Getting "unexpected numeric constant" in code

Tags: r

I am trying to run my code but get the following error:

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in: "
>   if((final.string[1+loop.check]) !=
>   (final.string[string.length-loop.check])){
>        return FALSE"

My code is as below:

```
inputString = "aabb"
string.length <- nchar(inputString)
compare.list <- strsplit(inputString,"")
final.string <- unlist(compare.list)
loop.check <- 0L
if(string.length %% 2 == 0){
  loop.stop <- string.length/2
}
if(string.length %% 2 == 1){
  loop.stop <- (string.length -1) / 2
}
while (loop.check<=loop.stop){
  if((final.string[1+loop.check]) != (final.string[string.length-loop.check])){
    return FALSE
    break
  }
  else{
    loop.check <- loop.check + 1
  }
}
if(loop.check-1==loop.stop){
  return TRUE
}
```

If I run just the `(final.string[1+loop.check]) != (final.string[string.length-loop.check])` portion then the console returns FALSE so the code for the if statement condition seems to be working. However, when attempting to run the whole script I get the above error.

Comment: I think it should be `return(FALSE)` not `return FALSE`

Comment: That's what @RichardTelford said, to use `return` in R, you shoud put it inside a parenthesis. But it's not a function to use `return`, just `break` must be enough, except you are using this code inside a function. If this is the case, `break` isn't needed, the loop is already broken with `return`.

Comment: @RichardTelford Well that seemed to work thanks! I still don't understand why it would give the unexpected numeric constant error for the if statement though. Do you know the reason?

Comment: You get the same error with `4 FALSE`, and an equivalent error with `4 "FALSE"`. It is not the `if` statement.